# jQuery (almost) equivalent of PHP's strip_tags()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, strip-tags

Is there a jQuery version of this function?

> string **strip_tags**( string $str [,
>   string $allowable_tags ] )

strip all tags and content inside them from a string except the ones defined in the allowable tags string.

like:

```
var stripped = strip_tags($('#text').html(), '<p><em><i><b><strong><code>');
```

from:

```
<div id="text">
  <p> paragraph </p>
  <div> should be stripped </div>
</div>
```

Comment: [phpjs.org](http://phpjs.org/functions/strip_tags:535) offers a port of this function.

Comment: `strip_tags` [does _not_ remove the content of stripped tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php).

Comment: When a tag is stripped, do you expect its child elements to be removed too? Can you please clarify?

Comment: (So please make clear in your question whether you want `strip_tags`'s behaviour, or the behaviour that you think it has. :D)

Comment: the behaviour you think I think it has :D yes, I want the content to be stripped to (including children if there are any any)

Comment: actually I changed my mind :) stripping only the tags is better in my case. the function from phpjs.org is great!

Comment: FYI, don't use regex because [bad things](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/266535) happen

Answer (score 36, accepted):

To remove *just the tags, and not the content*, which is how PHP's `strip_tags()` behaves, you can do:

```
var whitelist = "p"; // for more tags use the multiple selector, e.g. "p, img"
$("#text *").not(whitelist).each(function() {
    var content = $(this).contents();
    $(this).replaceWith(content);
});
```

[**Try it out here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/JEnvr/3/)

Comment: I've tried $("*").each()... and that seems to work fine. unless I'm missing something.

Comment: How to make this work on textareas? e.g. if i press a button then all html tags inside the textarea should be striped.

Comment: What about `<script>` tags? Those are not white-listed but still exist in the output.

Comment: Very nice one. Thank you !

Answer (score 30):

To remove all tags you can use

```
$('<div>Content</div>').text()
```

Comment: `$('dsfsadfasdfasdfasdf<a>sdfsdf</a>').text()` will give you
`"sdfsdf"` thus loosing the first part of the text.

Comment: Yes, it will work only when text wrapped inside some html tag

Comment: so do `$('<p>'+content+'</p>').text();`

Comment: `.text()` is more equivalent to PHP `htmlspecialchars()` than `strip_tags()`. Example: `outside html - <strong>inside html</strong>` `strip_tags` will be `outside html - inside html` but `.text()` will be  `outside html - <strong>inside html</strong>` where `<` is `&lt;` and `>` is `&gt;`

Comment: XSS warning: This method will also decode entities, e.g. `Foo &lt;script&gt;alert('XSS')&lt;/script&gt; <span>Bar</span>` will turn into `Foo <script>alert('XSS')</script> Bar`. PHP's `strip_tags` does not do that.

Answer (score 14):

Just use a regular expression:

```
html.replace( /<.*?>/g, '' );
```

Done. :)

For the `p` tag:

```
html.replace( /<[^p].*?>/g, '' );
```

For other tags, it gets more complicated.

Comment: line breaks breaks this rx: `'<tag\n>'.replace(/<.*?>/g,'') // <tag\n>`
to overcome this use `[\s\S]` instead of dot: `/<[\s\S]*?>/g`

Comment: ...or `/<[^>]*>/g`

Answer (score 11):

This worked for me:

```
function strip_tags(str) {
    str = str.toString();
    return str.replace(/<\/?[^>]+>/gi, '');
}
```

Comment: Voted for that one, because it's the only answer that does its work without side effects. I'd cut a half point if I could, since this function doesn't allow tag whitelisting (which I do not need).

Answer (score 7):

Even if this is an old thread i think it could be useful for those who are still looking for an answer.

The [Locutus.io function](http://locutus.io/php/strings/strip_tags/) seems to be the best solution:

```
function strip_tags (input, allowed) {
      allowed = (((allowed || '') + '').toLowerCase().match(/<[a-z][a-z0-9]*>/g) || []).join('')
      var tags = /<\/?([a-z][a-z0-9]*)\b[^>]*>/gi
      var commentsAndPhpTags = /<!--[\s\S]*?-->|<\?(?:php)?[\s\S]*?\?>/gi
      return input.replace(commentsAndPhpTags, '').replace(tags, function ($0, $1) {
        return allowed.indexOf('<' + $1.toLowerCase() + '>') > -1 ? $0 : ''
      })
}
```

Example 1:

```
strip_tags('<p>Kevin</p> <br /><b>van</b> <i>Zonneveld</i>', '<i><b>')
```

returns 1: `'Kevin <b>van</b> <i>Zonneveld</i>'`

Example 2:

```
strip_tags('<p>Kevin <img src="someimage.png" onmouseover="someFunction()">van <i>Zonneveld</i></p>', '<p>')
```

returns 2: `'<p>Kevin van Zonneveld</p>'`

Example 3:

```
strip_tags("<a href='http://kvz.io'>Kevin van Zonneveld</a>", "<a>")
```

returns 3: `"<a href='http://kvz.io'>Kevin van Zonneveld</a>"`

Example 4:

```
strip_tags('1 < 5 5 > 1')
```

returns 4: `'1 < 5 5 > 1'`

Example 5:

```
strip_tags('1 <br/> 1')
```

returns 5: `'1  1'`

Example 6:

```
strip_tags('1 <br/> 1', '<br>')
```

returns 6: `'1 <br/> 1'`

Example 7:

```
strip_tags('1 <br/> 1', '<br><br/>')
```

returns 7: `'1 <br/> 1'`

Answer (score 4):

Not an actual answer, but a word of caution (depending on what you're trying to do with this):

IMHO, in almost **all** cases, input sanitization should be done on the server side (in this case, using the native PHP functions). If your intent is to **replace** PHP functionality with client-side functionality, I would *strongly* advise against it.

Why?

Just because you're authoring a website, it doesn't mean that:

1. Your users have JavaScript enabled. If you aren't submitting your form strictly through script (using submit buttons, etc), it still allows users to submit invalid data (such as <script> tags, etc.)
2. Requests may not actually be initiated by a browser at all, circumventing any JS-based input sanitization.

Again, not really answering your question, but a word of caution based on where you could possibly be headed based on your question :)

Comment: no, I'm trying to allow visitors to "quote' comments when they comment. and when they click the quote button, I want the text from the comment they quoted to appear in the textarea, without tags, because it may scare them

Comment: @Alex - have a look at the example linked in my answer. I have deliberately coloured the `p` tags to emphasize that the 'whitelist' remains unaltered. All text is preserved.

Comment: @Alex - I think you meant to accept karim79's answer, not mine :)

Comment: Downvoted because the "answer" was not an answer and assumed OP was ignorant and didn't know what they needed. Best to understand why someone asks something before preaching against it based on assumed use-cases.

Comment: @mikeschinkel: it's not every day one gets down voted over two years after the fact :)

Answer (score 4):

To remove all tags, could use:

```
var StrippedString = OriginalString.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");
```

Code from: [Strip HTML Tags in JavaScript](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/strip-html-tags-in-javascript/)

Comment: no need for parentheses `str.replace(/<[^>]+>/ig, "")` would work the same

Answer (score 2):

You can try this, probably best solution: http://phpjs.org/functions/strip_tags/

Answer (score 1):

### UPDATE

Use the following to strip tags while keeping content

```
$('#text').find('p').contents().unwrap();
```

This will strip `p` tag where `p` is a child element of '#text'.

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/YWCsH/

Comment: That's not what `strip_tags` does. The OP says that content from inside stripped tags is removed, but [that's not true](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php).

Comment: @Hussein: Actually neither his text nor his example make it clear either way (he merely describes what `strip_tags` does, incorrectly). The only thing we can go on is that he wants a port of `strip_tags`, which does _not_ behave as your Javascript does.

Comment: It's a she. This is what i understood from her question regardless to whether she referenced `strip_tags` correctly.

Comment: @Hussein: Fair enough. It's a gamble either way: let's wait and see. :)

Comment: @Alex: Sorry; I didn't check your gender. Reflex typing. :)

Comment: xss warning, a safe string like this `&lt;script&gt;evil()&lt;script&gt;` will translate to an evil script with this method