# Use getElementById() on non-current HTML document

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox, getelementbyid

Essentially, I want to pull text within a div tag from a document on my server to place it in the current document. To explain the reason: I want to pull a headline from a "news article" to use it as the text for a link to that article.

For example, within the target HTML is the tag:

```
<div id='news-header'>Big Day in Wonderland</div>
```

So in my current document I want to use javascript to set the text within my anchor tags to that headline, i.e.:

```
<a href='index.php?link=to_page'>Big Day in Wonderland</a>
```

I'm having trouble figuring out how to access the non-current document in JS.

Thanks in advance for your help.

ADDED: Firefox style issue (see comment below).

Comment: ow about using JSON to get the headlines from the server?

Comment: Updating this problem with a minor extended problem: Firefox seems to not only pull in the text I want, but also the style (font-size, font-family, etc.) from its source div! This isn't happening in Chrome or IE. Thoughts?

Comment: The sub-issue in the above comment was resolved [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10726202/stripping-html-from-jquery-load-result).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, I would try to solve an issue only with the tools specified by the user; but if you are using javascript, there really is no good reason not to just use jQuery.

```
<a id='mylink' href='url_of_new_article' linked_div='id_of_title'></a>

$(function() {
    var a = $('#mylink');
    a.load(a.attr('href') + ' #' + a.attr('linked_div'));
});
```

That little function up there can help you update all your link's text dynamically.  If you have more than one, you can just put it in a `$('a').each()` loop and call it a day.

update to support multiple links on condition:

```
$(function() {
    $('a[linked_div]').each(function() {
        var a = $(this);
        a.load(a.attr('href') + ' #' + a.attr('linked_div'));
     });
});
```

The selector makes sure that only the links with the existence of the attribute 'linked_div' will be processed.

Comment: Sorry, I added jQuery tag as I do have jQuery code already. So your code above makes sense except for the load() attributes passed in....In my example, that would equate to `a.load('index.php?link=to_page news-header')`, is that correct?

Comment: Update: read up on the load() API, and I see that that is exactly what your code does...pull from the specified path to the remote HTML doc along with the #id attr passed in. I will throw this code in and let you know the result!

Comment: OK, so the innerHTML of my anchor tag isn't updating with the above code. I checked the run-time code, and the href path to the remote file is correct, and I added an attr `linked_div='#news-header'` to the anchor tag. But the innerHTML remains blank at run-time. I call the above function within the `$(document).ready(function()...` jQuery block. Thoughts?

Comment: No worries, I figured it needed to be there. :)  Unfortunately, my link innerHTML still isn't getting updated. Is the likely cause that it isn't finding the remote doc from the href I'm passing it? If so, how can I check to see if the jQuery code is reaching/reading the remote file?

Comment: UPDATE (partially solved!): Got it working with one link! Now, I have 2-4 links per page that I'd like to do this with, but I can't cycle thru all links as this doesn't apply to them all (only links to other articles). Of course, the issue is that I can't assign them all the same id (right now I'm iterating: #link-1, #link-2...). How would I handle this on the jQuery side? Thanks so much for getting me this far @rkw!

Comment: The jQuery selector is really powerful. Look at the update on the post.  By adding 'a[linked_div]' instead of just 'a', it will only bring back the elements with that attribute.  You can even filter on that attribute if you want, e.g. 'a[linked_div="something"]'

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you once again.

Comment: Sorry @rkw, I do have one final hurdle. It seems my links are now taking on the css styling of the id referenced by `linked_div`, despite having styling for its own css class (the `linked_div` styling must be overriding its class styling). Is this expected, and is there a workaround?

Comment: Verified that `load()` is indeed putting the source div tags in with the innerHTML. So instead of just putting `Headline Text` in my destination link, it's putting `<div id='news_header'>Headline Text</div>`. How do I just get the text without the source div tags?

Comment: UPDATE: got it working by cleaning out the add'l div tags in the callback function, a la [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5601903/jquery-almost-equivalent-of-phps-strip-tags/5601929#5601929). Not sure if this is the best or cleanest way, but it works.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure where you're getting your HTML but, assuming you already have it in a string, you could [create a document of your own](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/DOMImplementation.createDocument), stuff your HTML into it, and then use the standard [`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Document.getElementById) to pull out the piece you want. For example:

```
var doc = document.implementation.createDocument('http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml', 'html', null);
doc.documentElement.innerHTML = '<body><div>Nonsense</div><div id="news-header">Big Day in Wonderland</div><p>pancakes</p></body>';
var h = doc.getElementById('news-header');
// And now use `h` like any other DOM object.
```

Live version: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/ZZq2z/1/

Answer (score 1):

You need to pull the content of the remote document into the current DOM, as QuentinUK mentioned.  I'd recommend something like jQuery's [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method

Comment: Thanks guys. I actually do have jQuery code on my page already, so if that's the way to go, I'll research that route. So I'm assuming I can use jQuery's load() method to load my remote HTML file as an object in javascript? At that point can I use getElementById(), or is there an equivalent in jQuery to pull the text I need?

Comment: @kougar24: Yes, jQuery is the way to go if you have it, DOM wrangling in plain JavaScript isn't that much fun unless you really like typing.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, jQuery certainly was the way to go.