# Stripping HTML from jQuery load() result

Tags: php, jquery, html

This is a followup to the solution for [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7072832/use-getelementbyid-on-non-current-html-document)

I am using jQuery's `load()` function to pull a headline within a div tag from one page to another within my site. This works wonderfully.

The problem is, `load()` *also* pulls the div tag itself, which I do not want, as it then gets formatted via CSS like the source page.

Here is the PHP:

```
function get_team_articles($team_id, $feat=0) {
    .
    .
    .
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($r)) {
        $page = explode('_', $row['page_id']);
        (is_numeric($page[1]))
            ? $pre = 'wk_'
            : $pre = '';
        $arr[] =    $page[0] . " | " . $pre . $page[1] . ": " . "
                    <a linked_div='news_header'
                    linked_path='../news/" . $page[0] . "/" . $pre . $page[1] . "/" . $page[1] . "_" . $page[2] . ".html'
                    href='index.php?view=news&yr=" . $page[0] . "&wk=" . $page[1] . "&pg=" . $page[2] . "'></a>";
    }

    $articles = implode('<br/>', $arr);
    return $articles;
}
```

Notice the `linked_div` and `linked_path` attributes within the anchor tag, which are used in my jQuery:

```
function set_team_headlines(){
    $('#section-articles > a').each(function() {
        var a = $(this);
        a.load(a.attr('linked_path') + ' #' + a.attr('linked_div'));
    });
}
```

Obviously I cannot strip the HTML tags within the anchor tags in PHP, because the server doesn't have the text within the anchor tags upon loading; so I assume I need to strip the HTML in jQuery after the `load()` call...and that is what I cannot figure out how to do. :)

The result I *want* is:

```
<a href="...">My headline</a>
```

The result I'm *getting* is:

```
<a href="..."><div id="news_header">My headline</div></a>
```

Hopefully this makes sense. I think I provided more detail than I needed to. Thanks!

Comment: ultimately `load` fetches the whole page and strip out for your ease. Why dont you do `find('div').remove()` from the final result ?

Comment: @Jashwant You mean like `a.load(a.attr('linked_path') + ' #' + a.attr('linked_div')).find('div').remove();`? If so, that fails to strip off the `<div>` tag, and results in the same problematic solution my original code had.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Navigate down one more level in your `.load` selector

```
a.load(a.attr('linked_path') + ' #news_header');
```

If your news_header id isn't unique, it isn't valid to select by that id (ID's must be unique!)

To get around that issue, use this:

```
a.load(a.attr('linked_path') + ' #' + a.attr('linked_div') + ' div');
```

**Edit:**
`.load` actually includes the targeted element when appending html instead of appending the target element's children. I would move to using `$.get()`.

```
$.get(a.attr('linked_path')).done(function(html) {
    a.text($(html).filter("#news_header").text());
});
```

Comment: Sorry, @Kevin-B, `news_header` is an id, not a class. I'll edit my original post.

Comment: Right, but on the source page (`linked_path`), the ID _is_ unique. On the destination page they would not be, but I don't want that div/ID populated anyway (back to the original issue at hand).

Comment: see my last edit, it should work either way. At least try the first one. If news_header is unique on the page you are requesting with .load, that is what you should use.

Comment: The first, with `' #news_header'`, produces the same result as my problematic original (still contains `<div id='news_header'>`). The second breaks the core functionality of the `load()` (i.e. doesn't pull the headline text at all).

Comment: Ah, yeah that makes sense. load loads in the selected element and it's children, not just it's children. I suggest moving away from .load and using $.get in this case. I'll update answer.

Comment: Thanks Kevin, unfortunately the `$.get` code you have above does not work (does not pull the headline text).

Comment: Modify the selector until it does. I don't have your html to work with. Try `.filter` instead of `.find`, etc.

Comment: `.filter` worked! Thanks so much. Now I have to go research the difference between `.filter` and `.find`. :)

Comment: .filter worked because your `.get` is returning `<html>` and `<body>` tags and `#news_header` is a direct child of `<body>`, and jquery removes `<html>` and `<body>` from the html when you wrap it in `$()`. Did i guess correctly?

Comment: I threw in `alert(html)` above the `a.text...` within `$.get` and the output was `<div id='news_header'>[headline]</div><div id='news_body'>Lorem ipsum...</div>`.

Comment: That makes sense. the html is two elements that are siblings of each other, so you needed `.filter` to filter to only the news header.

Comment: That does make sense. And thank you again; my page now functions exactly as I had imagined.