# Remove form tag from remote page html fetched from ajax request

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I want the HTML of remote aspx page to another page on which I am working with ajax request. I want the form tag removed from the remote page HTML  also I want the+ scripts to be executed too which are on remote page.

Remote Page:
Test.aspx:

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="wrapper">
<asp:textbox runat="server" ID="TextBox1"></asp:textbox>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

    alert('hello');
</script>

</form>
```

Working Page:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" %>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="en-us">
<head runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="foo">
    </div>
    <script>


        $.ajax({ url: '/test.aspx',
            data: {},
            dataType: "html",
            success: function (response) {
                $('#foo').html('');
                var fragment = $(response).find('#wrapper');
                $('#foo').append(fragment);

            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {

            }
        });
    </script>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
<script runat="server">


</script>
```

Comment: So are you editing it through ASP or jQuery? If jQuery, try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5601929/1013082

Comment: Can you give explain me the same in my context?

Answer (score 1):

have you tried using jquery.load()?

http://api.jquery.com/load/

with this you can specify an id of a container on the remote page. Like this.

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
    $('#result').load('ajax/test.html #container');
});
```

Comment: With this line "       $('#foo').load('/test.aspx #form1');" no alert is firing.

Comment: that's because asp.net transforms the id of serverbound items like your form. Put a div around your alert like <div id="divalert"><!--alert goes here--></div> Then call $('#foo').load('/test.aspx #divalert');

Comment: Still no alert. Here is my code of remote page <%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="wrapper">
<asp:textbox runat="server" ID="TextBox1"></asp:textbox>
</div>
<div id="divalert">
<script type="text/javascript">

    alert('hello');
</script>
</div> 

</form>

Comment: you do have a container on the parent page with the id of "foo" right? The jquery code should be on the parent page too. I edited my original answer to show you'll need to wrap it.