# Removing all non br and span tags?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Any way to remove all non span and non br html tags from a html string? But keeping the text inside them?

Cheers

Comment: What's your input string? And you want to remove *all* tags, except for `br` and `span`?

Comment: Not sure of anything builtin, but there is http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php for php

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5601903/jquery-almost-equivalent-of-phps-strip-tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used:

```
$content = $(elem);
$content.find(':not(br, span)').contents().unwrap();
$content.find(':not(br, span)').remove()
```

The first line unwraps all elements with content (like `<span>some text</span>`)
the second line will remove all remaining elements without content (like `<hr />`, `<img />`, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$(elem).find('*').not('br, span').unwrap()
```