# how to remove all style except font-weight using jquery in all elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, nicedit

i am using nicedit as editor in my app and the users of our website use to paste data from MS word or some other sources, hence the ui breaks up, so we have decided to remove all formatting from the html using jquery.

What i did is removed all inline style and class, but it is creating problem as it is removing bold and italics too, where as we want to retain it.

is their any simple way of removing all style except bold using jquery.

example :

```
<div style="color:red; font-size:13px; font-weight:bold;">test div </div>
```

in the above element i want it as

```
<div style="font-weight:bold;">test div </div>
```

Comment: Have you attempted anything yourself? See answers for [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5601903/jquery-almost-equivalent-of-phps-strip-tags).

Comment: The statement “it is removing bold and italics too, where as we want to retain it” conflicts with the rest of the question: do you want to retain bolding only, or both bolding and italic?

Comment: i want to retain bold and italics both

Comment: Can you fiddle your question in http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: You should edit the question to reflect the intended meaning. The question should be understandable as standalone, without reading the comments.

Comment: You should also clarify what you mean by “all formatting”. Should e.g. links be removed, because they by default affect formatting, or heading elements, or lists, or generally HTML elements that have some default formatting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the only way is to store the styles you want, remove them all and then set them again.

```
$('.selector').each(function() {
  var keepStyle, $el;
  $el = $(this);
  keepStyle = {
    font-weight: $el.css('font-weight'),
    font-style : $el.css('font-style')
  };

  $el.removeAttr('style')
    .css(keepStyle);
})
```

Comment: The code does not run; the property names `font-weight` and `font-style` must be quoted. The code affects only the elements that match `.selector`, not any descendants; this should be clarified. Moreover, this does not remove all formatting, e.g. the formatting created by `<u>...</u>` or `<font color=red>red</font>`.

Answer (score 1):

I havent tested it try if it works

```
 $('div').each(function(){
   weight = $(this).css('font-weight');
   $(this).attr('style','');
   $(this).removeClass();
   $(this).css('font-weight',  weight);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store this attributes as data using [jquery data method](http://api.jquery.com/data/)
and restore after clearing all styles

Comment: i don't have that option as the user paste some data in the editor and we are saving that data to the database, and in the website we have to remove the formatting from the elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
var $temp = $('<div><div style="color:red; font-size:13px; font-weight:bold;">test div </div></div>');

 $temp.find('*').each(function(){
    var fontWeight = $(this).css('font-weight');
$(this).removeAttr('style');
if(fontWeight!=undefined){
     $(this).attr('style','font-weight:'+fontWeight);
}
});
```