# Remove all tags in html string except <a>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I'v got some html which I must clear from all tags except one concrete `<a>` with known class.
Here is the html:

```
var string = '<span class="so_sentence"><span> Some text <a class="so_footnote-ref" href="#footnote-104008-4" id="footnote-104008-4-backlink">[1]</a></span></span>';
```

I have JQuery attached, so I get the jQuery object of the string.

```
var html = $(string);
```

Now I have to clear the string from all the span and probably other tags, except this `<a>`:

```
<a class="so_footnote-ref" href="#footnote-104008-4" id="footnote-104008-4-backlink">[1]</a>
```

So my final string should be:

```
'Some text <a class="so_footnote-ref" href="#footnote-104008-4" id="footnote-104008-4-backlink">[1]</a>'
```

Also it must be possible to call this function on the result, so it must be of appropriate type:

```
function _trim(string){
    return string.replace(/(?:(?:^|\n)\s+|\s+(?:$|\n))/g,'').replace(/\s+/g,' ');
}
```

Comment: ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags?rq=1 ... the general rule is that you cannot process arbitrary markup with regex. (If you have a special case that you *only have a single* `a` tag without complicated nesting, it might work.

Comment: @musefan did I talk about parsing?

Comment: @musefan The OP wants to remove all tags other than the a with help of a regex, or am I mistaken? In my eyes, that's processing html markup with a regex.

Comment: I've found some interressting post in another thread.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/5601929/3303652
This might help you.
example: http://jsfiddle.net/JEnvr/229/

Comment: I'm not forced to use RegExp, so any solution is fine :)

Comment: I realized I misunderstood your requirements earlier, so I hastily posted a new solution. I subsequently realized that it had some errors, so I've fixed those, and tested out the solution in a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mhfaust/wJWJu/.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(string).find(':not(a)').contents().unwrap()
```

This will vorky with every piece of html code.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/E3RWL/1/

Comment: The OP has asked for the result as an HTML **string**, otherwise a good answer. This will work: `var result = $("<div>").append(html).html();` (assuming `html` is the result of your current function)

Comment: @HarryFink I did try your suggestion myself and had problems with getting the result as single string.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a function I found for you:

You can read more about this at: http://phpjs.org/functions/strip_tags/

Javascript:

```
var ret = strip_tags('<p>Kevin</p> <br /><b>van</b> <i>Zonneveld</i>', '<i><b>');

// returns: 'Kevin <b>van</b> <i>Zonneveld</i>'

function strip_tags (input, allowed) {
  allowed = (((allowed || "") + "").toLowerCase().match(/<[a-z][a-z0-9]*>/g) || []).join(''); // making sure the allowed arg is a string containing only tags in lowercase (<a><b><c>)
  var tags = /<\/?([a-z][a-z0-9]*)\b[^>]*>/gi,
    commentsAndPhpTags = /<!--[\s\S]*?-->|<\?(?:php)?[\s\S]*?\?>/gi;
  return input.replace(commentsAndPhpTags, '').replace(tags, function ($0, $1) {
    return allowed.indexOf('<' + $1.toLowerCase() + '>') > -1 ? $0 : '';
  });
}
```

Comment: That's far to complicated to try and understand, but will this work on nested elements, like in the example?

Comment: I try it with the example from the opener. It works.

Comment: @musefan This will break, if there are several `a` elements present. As far as I understood, OP wants to remove everything except one a with a special class. http://jsfiddle.net/TH644/1/

Comment: Nonetheless this is a good start. The `a` tag is quite pleasent in it's nature that it can't be nested, so you could adapt the solution to this special case, but generally spoken as I already said Regex is not suited for this task. (*Regular* expression (linear) vs. a *context free* language will always fail: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy).