# JavaScript paste text to contenteditable with remove format

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want paste text to:

```
<div class="text" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

Then after paste i need that text will be with removed text formatting, but keep new lines.

I have this text this:

```
$(".text").bind({
    paste: function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            var text = $(".text").text();
            $('.text').text(text);
        }, 100);
    }
});
```

But it's not add new lines;

Comment: Well you are removing the break tags....paragraphs, or whatever is adding the new lines. What element[s] is the new lines when you paste?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery (almost) equivalent of PHP's strip\_tags()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5601903/jquery-almost-equivalent-of-phps-strip-tags)

Comment: What i need: when user paste text, text became with clean format, but i need that new lines will remain where was <p> <div> <br> or new line. Someting like wast pasted to <textarea> but not like contenteditable

Comment: @pistou i found usefull part of code here, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found out what I needed. This code does my required job:

```
$(".text").bind({
        paste: function () {
            setTimeout(function () {
                var text = $(".text").html();

                text = text.replace(/<p[^>]*>/g, '').replace(/<\/p>/g, '<br><br>');
                text = text.replace(/<div[^>]*>/g, '').replace(/<\/p>/g, '<br><br>');

                $('.text').html(text);

                $(".text *").not("br").each(function() {
                    var content = $(this).contents();
                    $(this).replaceWith(content);
                });

            }, 1);
        }
    });
```