# Only allow certain tags in contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I have a contenteditable div and using keyboard shortcuts like `ctrl+i` the user is able to format the text. And as they type the `innerHTML` changes reflecting the tags i.e:

`Hello&nbsp;<i>thanks for&nbsp;<br><br>for showing up<b>&nbsp;y'all b</b></i>`

This is fine, and works well for my purposes. but the issue arises that when I go to print the html in a different `div` IF a user adds any other html tags, they could really mess up the application.

For instance, if they added a `<script>` tag or `style` etc.. How do I make it that the user is *only* allowed to add `<i>`, `<br>`, `<b>`, `<s>`, and `&nbsp;` without being able to add anything else?

Any ideas? Thank you

Comment: The easiest way to accomplish your goal is to maintain control over the input by using `document.execCommand()`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand

Comment: @RandyCasburn I'm sorry. I'm not quite following how that helps me?

Comment: I'm not sure it does directly other than allowing you to create a custom editor that allows them to type whatever text they want into the editor, and if they want to add emphasis, italics, bold, etc. you provide them a user interface to control that. The only other option is to parse the string and eliminate any thing that looks like a tag you don't want. That is inexact and may or may not achieve quality results for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you can use a regExpresion to avoid the "indeseables" tags. Some like

```
<textarea #data [(ngModel)]="value" (input)="replace(data)"></textarea>
<div [innerHtml]="valueParse">
</div>

replace(control:any)
{
   this.valueParse=control.value.replace(/<(?!br|i|u)((\w+))>/gm,"&lt$1&gt")
   .replace(/<\/(?!br|i|u)((\w+))>/gm,'&lt\/$1&gt');
}
```

See [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ftgmfg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: This works well. I also found this post that seems to work really well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46483672/2230430