# React Typescript specify type of children for svg component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, svg

I have this Svg wrapper component:

```
const Svg = ({ w, h, children, ...props }: SvgPropsType) => {
  return (
    <svg
      {...props}
      xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'
      width={w}
      height={h}
      viewBox={`0 0 ${w} ${h}`}>
      {children}
      <line></line>
    </svg>
  )
}
type SvgPropsType = {
  w: number,
  h: number,
  children: JSX.Element | JSX.Element[],
  props: SVGProps<SVGSVGElement>
}
```

I wish to type restrict the types of children that can be passed to the prop, so that they are valid `<svg>` descendents (i.e. `<line>`, `<polygon>`)?

Comment: Not possible if you want to use JSX syntax.

Comment: I think what you're looking fo ris something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53357161/only-allow-certain-tags-in-contenteditable-div)

Comment: You can do it in runtime, but Typescript validation seems to be impossible in that case